# Text element background color change

Tags: jquery, razor

I'm a little new to jquery so please bear with me.

I'm working on a registration system and have a password and confirm password text box. I would like to set the background-color of the confirm box whenever the contents of the two boxes change. Color would be based on if the contents of the boxes match.

EDIT - 
My original code was not changing the background color at all. I would like to have it change as the user types rather than on focus/blur.

My code is as follows.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="newpassword"/>
<input type = "password" name = "confirm" id="confirm"/>
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="Register"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#password').change(function () {
            if ($('#newpassword').val().Equals($('#confirm').val())) {
                $('#confirm').attr("backgroundcolor", "green");
                $('#Register').attr("disabled", "");
            } else {
                $('#confirm').attr("backgroundcolor", "red");
                $('#Register').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });
        $('#confirm').change(function () {
            if ($('#newpassword').val().Equals($('#confirm').val())) {
                $('#confirm').attr("backgroundcolor", "green");
                $('#Register').attr("disabled", "");
            } else {
                $('#confirm').attr("backgroundcolor", "red");
                $('#Register').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        })
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And ? What is not working ? Error message ?

Comment: And what problem you are facing

Comment: You left off a `});` at the end.

Comment: the missing }); was a result of copy/pasting the relevant portion of my jquery. I missed the closing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newpassword, #confirm').change(function () {
        var $n = $('#newpassword'),
            $c = $('#confirm'),
            newp = $n.val(),
            conf = $c.val();
        if (newp === conf) {
            $c.css('background-color', 'green');
            $n.prop('disabled', false)
        } else {
            $c.css('background-color', 'red');
            $n.prop('disabled', true)
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this is what you wanted to do.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/DgqX7/)

Comment: Thank you this is a very elegant solution. However you disabled the wrong element. It should disable the register button. I've changed the change function to keypress and that seems to be more what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DocSmiley ah I see it now, don't know why I thought newpassword should be disabled

Answer (score 2):

Use css method because backgroundcolor isn't an attribute.

```
$('#confirm').css("backgroundColor", "green");
```

Comment: backgroundcolor is not a css property.

Comment: This is only one of the problems.

Comment: That' right.. write backgroundColor (it's also working in jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code http://jsfiddle.net/pQpYX/:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#confirm').keypress(function (event) {
        if ($('#newpassword').val() == ($('#confirm').val() + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) {
            $('#confirm').css("background-color", "green");
            $('#newpassword').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('#confirm').css("background-color", "red");
            $('#newpassword').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```